# Symfony2: many-to-many with extra columns no Lazy in Twig

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, twig, lazy-evaluation

I know, there are a lot of posts about this topic, but for me it is imposible to get the right solution.

I have 2 entities with the relationship many-to-many and in that relationship many colums (that means 3 entities). I have two questions:

1. The SQL is Lazy-loadinig, but I write "SELECT l, ul ...", so I want to select both tables. Why still Lazy-loading?? is There any config anywhere??
2. How can I show it in my Twig's Templates??

My entities are more or less like that:
Usuario:

```
/**
 * Usuario
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 */
class Usuario
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nombre", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nombre;

    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UsuarioLibro", mappedBy="usuario")
     */
    private $libros;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->libros = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    ...    

    /**
     * Get libros
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getLibros()
    {
        return $this->libros;
    }
}
```

Libros:

```
/**
 * Libro
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 */
class Libro
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="titulo", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $titulo;

    ...

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UsuarioLibro", mappedBy="libro")
    */
    private $usuarios;

    ...

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->usuarios = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    ...

    /**
     * Get usuarios
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getUsuarios()
    {
        return $this->usuarios;
    }
}
```

UsuariosLibros (the relationship):

```
/**
 * usuario_libro
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="usuario_libro")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class UsuarioLibro
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tener", type="boolean", options={"default":0})
     */
    private $tener;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="leer", type="boolean", options={"default":0})
     */
    private $leer;

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="usuario", inversedBy="libros")
     */
    private $usuario;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="libro", inversedBy="usuarios")
     */
    private $libro;

    public function __construct(Usuario $usuario, Libro $libro)
    {
        $this->usuario = $usuario;
        $this->libro = $libro;
    }

    ...

    /**
     * Get usuario
     *
     * @return \JavierGlez\Osprey\FrontendBundle\Entity\usuario 
     */
    public function getUsuario()
    {
        return $this->usuario;
    }

    /**
     * Get libro
     *
     * @return \JavierGlez\Osprey\FrontendBundle\Entity\libro 
     */
    public function getLibro()
    {
        return $this->libro;
    }
}
```

I can serch all the content with this SQL:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            "SELECT l, ul FROM JGOspreyFrontendBundle:Libro l
            LEFT JOIN l.usuarios ul
            LEFT JOIN ul.usuario u
            JOIN  l.colecciones c
            WHERE c.id = :idColeccion AND (u.id = :idUsuario OR u.id IS NULL)")
       ->setParameters(array('idColeccion'=>$idColeccion, 'idUsuario'=>$idUsuario));
```

When I try to debug the variable, then the program gets blocked.

Anyone can help me???
Cheers

Comment: The entities structure are not correct; when you create bidirectional relationship, one side should has `mappedBy` and the other side should has `inversedBy`. Check this link for more info http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: Yes, I know: "Usuario" and "Libro" are mappedBy, but "UsuarioLibro" is inversedBy. You can see, o maybe you mean another thing. Any way, I want to check the link that you write. Thanks!!